# JavaMail - Can't load SASL authenticator

Tags: android, oauth, jakarta-mail, sasl

I'm getting the following error when trying to connect to the imap store using JavaMail in an Android app:

> IMAP DEBUG: Can't load SASL authenticator: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:  [class com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol, class java.lang.String, class java.util.Properties, boolean, class java.io.PrintStream, class java.lang.String]

The issue I am having appears to the the same as the one describe here:
[ProGuard java.lang.NoSuchMethodException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27687973/proguard-java-lang-nosuchmethodexception)

...but the solution of adding the line to the proguard did not help.

```
public class OAuth2SaslClientFactory implements SaslClientFactory {
    private static final Logger logger =
    Logger.getLogger(OAuth2SaslClientFactory.class.getName());

    public static final String OAUTH_TOKEN_PROP =
      "mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms.oauth2.oauthToken";

    public SaslClient createSaslClient(String[] mechanisms,
                                 String authorizationId,
                                 String protocol,
                                 String serverName,
                                 Map<String, ?> props,
                                 CallbackHandler callbackHandler) {
    boolean matchedMechanism = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < mechanisms.length; ++i) {
         if ("XOAUTH2".equalsIgnoreCase(mechanisms[i])) {
           matchedMechanism = true;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (!matchedMechanism) {
         logger.info("Failed to match any mechanisms");
         return null;
      }
      return new OAuth2SaslClient((String) props.get(OAUTH_TOKEN_PROP),
                            callbackHandler);
   }

   public String[] getMechanismNames(Map<String, ?> props) {
      return new String[] {"XOAUTH2"};
   }
}

public OAuth2Provider() {
      super("Google OAuth2 Provider", 1.0,
            "Provides the XOAUTH2 SASL Mechanism");
          put("SaslClientFactory.XOAUTH2",
                  "com.app.OAuth2SaslClientFactory");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to determine exactly what in the proguard was missing, but I did end getting the project to run by adding the following line to the proguard file:

```
-dontshrink
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using [JavaMail 1.5.2](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home), which includes [built-in OAuth2 support](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2), and thus doesn't require any of that code you've included above?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. It does not appear to work on Android and all posts I've found say the same thing, you need to support SASL yourself because you can't use 1.5.2 on Android.

Comment: What a shame that Android isn't Java Compatible, huh?

Comment: Yes, it is a little frustrating. Any advice on getting past this issue in Android?

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't use Android.